# Nginx rewrite not redirecting

Tags: nginx, redirect, query-string

I would like to rebuild a URL and redirect from `https://test.com/info/schoolName/detail` to `https://test.com/school-info?name=schoolName` with Nginx.

I have tried

```
location ~ ^/(school-info)(?:/(.*))?$ {
  include /etc/nginx/servers/platform/shared/headers_proxy.conf;

  proxy_set_header Host $backend_netlify_main;
  proxy_ssl_server_name on;

  proxy_pass https://$backend_netlify_main/$1/$2;
}

...
...

location ~* ^/(info|info/)$ {
  include /etc/nginx/servers/platform/shared/headers_proxy.conf;

  rewrite ^/info/(.?)/(.*)$ /school-info?school=$1 permanent;

  proxy_pass $backend_cms;
}
```

however, if I visit `https://test.com/info/byu/detail` it's not doing a redirect at all.

**EDIT**: The `/detail` at the end is not important at all, so regardless of what is at the end of the URL the `/schoolName/` is the most important part to be passed as a query parameter.

Comment: Of course it won't redirect since you limit `location` URI to either `/info` or `/info/` with the `$` anchor sign. BTW this regex better be written as `^/info/?$`. Do you want to say you didn't use `detail` substring from `/info/schoolName/detail` at all? What should happen for the request like `/info/schoolName/detail2` for example?

Comment: And of course the `^/info/(.?)/(.*)$` regex don't match `/info/schoolName/detail` URI unless the `schoolName` substring is only one character long.

Comment: everything after `schoolName/` can be ignored, the most important part is the name being passed as a param in the new url

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like

```
location / { # "default" location
    # do redirection for '/info/...' URIs
    rewrite ^/info/([^/])* /school-info/$1 permanent;
    # otherwise pass request to the default backend
    proxy_pass $backend_cms;
}
location /school-info {
  include /etc/nginx/servers/platform/shared/headers_proxy.conf;

  proxy_set_header Host $backend_netlify_main;
  proxy_ssl_server_name on;

  proxy_pass https://$backend_netlify_main;
}
```

if you need to pass a request as `/school-info/schoolName`, or

```
location / { # "default" location
    # do redirection for '/info/...' URIs
    rewrite ^/info/([^/])* /school-info?name=$1 permanent;
    # otherwise pass request to the default backend
    proxy_pass $backend_cms;
}
location /school-info {
  include /etc/nginx/servers/platform/shared/headers_proxy.conf;

  proxy_set_header Host $backend_netlify_main;
  proxy_ssl_server_name on;

  proxy_pass https://$backend_netlify_main/school-info$is_args$args;
}
```

if you need to pass a request as `/school-info?name=schoolName`.